# How do I create a VisualForce Apex page programatically from a method in a Visualforce class?

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

I'm trying to generate a Visualforce page for a certain data entry with certain controls and functionality which is essentially a dynamic controller page. Below is how I generate a page block.

```
        Component.Apex.PageBlock dynPageBlock = new Component.Apex.PageBlock();

        List<Schema.FieldSetMember> list_of_fields = getFieldsToDisplay();
        Component.Apex.PageBlockSection pbs = new Component.Apex.PageBlockSection();
        pbs.columns = 1;

        for(Schema.FieldSetMember fld : list_of_fields){
           // input field
           Component.Apex.InputField input_field = new Component.Apex.InputField();
           input_field.expressions.value = '{!FormObject.' + fld.getFieldPath() +'}';
           input_field.id = fld.getFieldPath();
           pbs.childComponents.add(input_field);
```

After this step, I wish to create a ApexPage which I need a API method to save it under APEX pages. Is this something possible to achieve in VisualForce? Curious about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is doable via Apex. You will need to use metadata API in this case. Andrew has a library for it: https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi . You can use it to generate your VF page. But sorry I don't have a sample code for it. But it should point you to where to start.